# C++/Arduino Passing pointer to 2D array stored in PROGMEM

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d, progmem

I have several const int 2D arrays globally stored in PROGMEM. for example:

```
const int image1[][17]PROGMEM = {
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}
}
```

I would like to read out this 2d image array in a function. Which image to read out should be specified in the argument.

```
void printImage(image)
{
  // do something with element i,j of image
  pgm_read_byte(image[i][j])
}
```

I am not very expierenced with the use of pointers etc. but I know that's the way to do it. Can you show me how to make it work?

EDIT1:
How I do it now (it works, but it is not elegant); I have the function printImage1() without any arguments, and in the body function I use:

```
pgm_read_byte(&image1[i][j])
```

to read out image1.
For image2, image3 etc. I copy the function printImage1 and change imgage1 from above to image2, image3 etc. This is redundant programming thats why I want to specify the image in the argumant using only one function printImage.

Comment: How *doesn't* it work now? What happens when you build your program? What happens when you run your program? Please elaborate!

Comment: I edited my question, please have a look! thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

`pgm_read_byte` takes the address of the byte you want to read. You could use

```
pgm_read_byte(&image[i][j])
```

or

```
pgm_read_byte(image[i] + j)
```

Note, however, that it is unusual to use `pgm_read_byte` on an array of `int` (which are 2 bytes wide on AVR). You should probably make `image1` a 2D array of `uint8_t` or use `pgm_read_word`.

Comment: using uint8_t instead of int indeed reduces the size, thanks for this remark